# Explicit type cast for Mongoose _id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

When I run the mongoose update script with the `$in` condition on the attribute `_id` set to a string like: `'56952ed6457e483a389c9fe4'` instead of `ObjectId('56952ed6457e483a389c9fe4')`, the query condition does not match. However, if I explicitly type `ObjectId(.)` the query works as expected.

Question: Do I need to explicitly type-cast a string to mongoose object to make it work?

**This works:**

```
db.apps.update(
  { $and: [ {name : 'a1'}, {_id : {$in : [Object('56952ed6457e483a389c9fe4')]}} ] }, 
  {"_id" : ObjectId("56952ed6457e483a389c9fe4"), name : "a1", intent_ids: [ObjectId('56952ed6457e483a389c9ff8'), ObjectId('56952ed6457e483a389c9ff9')]} 
);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
db.apps.update(
  { $and: [ {name : 'a1'}, {_id : {$in : ['56952ed6457e483a389c9fe4']}} ] }, 
  {"_id" : ObjectId("56952ed6457e483a389c9fe4"), name : "a1", intent_ids: [ObjectId('56952ed6457e483a389c9ff8'), ObjectId('56952ed6457e483a389c9ff9')]} 
);
```

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't need to as Mongoose will cast values to the fields' types as defined by the schema.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But, if I don't cast it in the `$in` clause, it does not work. Updated the question to show both the versions (one that works and one that doesn't). Thoughts?

Comment: Neither of the queries you show are using Mongoose though. Those look like shell queries where you need to do the casting yourself.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I think you are right. Sorry I just realized that!